# uncaught exception in destructors of static objects

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer

When I'm trying the [following code](https://godbolt.org/z/48seqEzv4):

```
#include <thread>

struct foo
{
    ~foo() noexcept(false) { throw 0; }
};

void func()
try
{
    static foo f;
}
catch(...)
{

}

int main()
{
    std::thread t{func};
    t.join();
}
```

the compiler gives me the following error:

`terminating due to uncaught exception of type int`

I then went to the standard to find a rule that would prohibit the above example from working, but I couldn't find that; and simply that's my problem.

The rule that I think it applies here is [[except.handle]/11](https://eel.is/c++draft/except#handle-11); this bullet says:

> Exceptions thrown in destructors of objects with static storage duration or in constructors of objects associated with non-block variables with static storage duration are not caught by a *function-try-block* on the main function.
>
> Exceptions thrown in destructors of objects with thread storage duration or in constructors of objects associated with non-block variables with thread storage duration are not caught by a *function-try-block* on the initial function of the thread.

I think the first part of this bullet is not applicable because the *function-try-block* is on function `func` not `main` function. Also, I see the second part of the bullet is not applicable because it talks about thread objects not static objects.

Was it the above rule that prohibited my example from working? If not, what is the correct rule from the standard to apply here?

Comment: This is such a weird idea that I'm not surprised the standard doesn't explicitly prohibit it.

Comment: That is, when the destructor runs, the control is not inside the corresponding `try`-block. Why should its `catch` be used?

Comment: `static foo f;` will be destroyed after `main` has exited (and before control is returned to the OS).  There will be no open catch handlers at that point.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "*Why should its catch be used?*" because that's what would happen if `f` is non-static variable. [see](https://godbolt.org/z/qf8aTsMPc)

Comment: @RichardCritten This is true. Can you standardize what you said?

Comment: Best I can do is [Static local variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) -  _"The destructor for a block-scope static variable is called [at program exit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit), but only if the initialization took place successfully."_

Comment: @Mia When the variable is non-static, it's destroyed right before the control leaves the function. But for the static one, that happens long after the control leaves the function.

Comment: @RichardCritten cppreference is perfect for simplifying the standard, but it's not a specification can totally rely on.

Comment: The behavior is explained in https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.term (which is also not a specification you can totally rely on, as explained per https://eel.is/c++draft/ intro.)

Comment: This is mad, but I'm always happy to see someone trying edge-cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant wording is in [[basic.start.term] p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.term#3):

> If the destruction of an object with static or thread storage duration exits via an exception, the function `std​::​terminate` is called ([[except.terminate]](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.terminate)).

The subsequent wording in [[except.handle] p11](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle#11) which you have found could be a note, assuming that the other content of the paragraph concerning construction is also covered elsewhere (it most likely is).
The reader has no reason to believe that a *function-try-block* for `main` would catch the exception when reading this paragraph; it is redundant.